# JavaScript guessing game with cookie

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Instruction:

> Create a number guessing game to generate a number between the range of 1 and 2. The game should prompt users for their username (saved in cookie). Set range as function parameter and prompt the player to predict the generated number between the given range, at a correct guess, the game should award the player a point (also saved in cookie), and move them to stage 2 by increasing the range limit value by 1, e.g range is from 1 and 3 for stage 2 and so on.

This is what I have done so far.

```
playButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const guessingGame = (range) => {
    const rndGuess = Math.floor(Math.random() * range) + 1;
    console.log(rndGuess);
    let point = 0;
    const playerName = prompt("Please enter username");
    setCookie("username", playerName, 1);
    const guess = prompt(`Predict a number between 1 and ${range}`);
    const playerGuess = Number(guess);

    if (rndGuess === playerGuess) {
      console.log(point, "point");
      point = point + 1;
      console.log(point);
      alert(`You won!, ${playerName}, You've scored ${point} point`);
      setCookie("point", point, 1);
      guessingGame(range + 1);
      point = point += 1;
      setCookie("point", point, 1);
    } else {
      point = 0;
      alert("You lose!");
    }
  };
  guessingGame(2);
});
```

problem: point does not increase, and I only want to prompt username once if `rndGuess === playerGuess` is true.

Comment: `point` is scoped to your function, so it will start back at 0 each time you call the function. You don't include your `setCookie()` function here (and AFAIK, it's not native to JS), but I'm assuming you're hoping to use that to store the point tally, and while you set your cookie, you never retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working this way

```
playButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const playerName = prompt("Please enter username");
  setCookie("username", playerName, 1);
  let point = 0;
  const guessingGame = (range) => {
    const rndGuess = Math.floor(Math.random() * range) + 1;
    console.log(rndGuess);
    const guess = prompt(`Predict a number between 1 and ${range}`);
    const playerGuess = Number(guess);

    if (rndGuess === playerGuess) {
      point = point + 1;
      setCookie("point", point, 1);
      alert(`You won!, ${playerName}, You've scored ${point} point`);
      guessingGame(range + 1);
    } else {
      point = 0;
      alert("You lose!");
    }
  };
  guessingGame(2);
});
```